# Regex: match everything before image

Tags: regex, inverse

url1: `/dir-images/no1/top-left.gif`
url2: `/test-1/test-2/test`

I want to match the path before the last slash if it is an image file(url1), aka `/dir-images/no1/`
and match the whole path if it is not(url2), `/test-1/test-2/test`

tried `^([\=\/\.\w-]+\/)+` this could get path before the last slash no matter what is after it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
^([\=/.\w-]+/)+((?!.*\.gif$).*|)
```

The part with `(?!)` is a lookahead. This is something like an if statement. There are two different lookaheads, `?=` and `?!`. The first one is a normal if, the second one is an 'if not'.

In your case, I just ask if the ending is not `gif`? And then I match everything.

Comment: Thanks! My question is if the ending is .gif, does it match the path before last slash? coz in my regex tool, it will not match anything.

Comment: @user1296363 you only want to know if the whole thing ends with .gif? then just try '\.gif$'

Comment: @ruakh I don't get the first part. I just fixed the other problem with a pipe, I totally forgot that.

Answer (score 0):

One way (with `perl` flavour):

```
m|\A(.*/(?(?!.*\.gif$).*))|
```

Explanation:

```
m| ... |              # Regexp.
\A                    # Begin of line.
(                     # Group 1.
  .*/                 # All characters until last slash.
  (?                  # Conditional expression.
    (?!.*\.gif$)      # If line doesn't end with '.gif', match...
    .*)               # ... until end of line.
)
```

---

**Testing...**

Content of `script.pl`:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    printf qq[%s\n], $1 if m|\A(.*/(?(?!.*\.gif$).*))|;
}

__DATA__
/dir-images/no1/top-left.gif
/test-1/test-2/test
```

Run it like:

```
perl script.pl
```

And following result:

```
/dir-images/no1/
/test-1/test-2/test
```